# Updating selected layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, print-composer, select, update

I have a legend in my Print Composer and then made some adjustments with some layers in my project. In the Print Composer, is there a simple way to adjust selected layers?

Of course I can delete the layers and re-import them, or I can update everything and then adjust my legend. But I'm kind of looking for a button saying "update selected layers".

Is there a function like that?

Comment: In witch version of QGIS are you working on? In witch way you want to adjust your legend in your print composer? Why do you want it dynamics? Please add some details

Answer (score 0):

Individual layers in the legend can be easily updated by right click on the layer and "set back to presettings". the English term is probably not 100% accurate but somethin like that.

Comment: To be more documented, please precise your question and your answer.